# Generate button only generates once and gets stuck after

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new to JS, and I'm trying to create a simple Rock paper scissors app. I have a generate button that generates a random option between Rock paper and scissors on both the user and computer board, However, whenever I click it, it only generates it once and if I click it again to randomize between rock paper and scissors again it doesn't work. Here's my JavaScript code:

```
let options = ['', '✋', '✌'];
let generatedOptions = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)]
let generatedOptions1 = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)]
let userBoard = document.getElementById('userBoard');
let computerBoard =document.getElementById('computerBoard');



let app = function () {
userBoard.innerHTML = generatedOptions
computerBoard.innerHTML = generatedOptions1
}
```

my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
</head>
<style>
.banner {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10%;
    font-size: 5vw;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>

<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; column-gap: 5%; height: 100%">
<div class="banner" id="userBoard"></div>
<div class="banner" id="computerBoard"></div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around; column-gap: 5%; height: 100%; margin- 
top: 2%">
<button onclick="app()">Generate</button>
<p>Computer Generated</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works every time the button is clicked, the problem is elsewhere, in this case it is in the fact that the same values ​​of the two variables (`generatedOptions` and `generatedOptions1`) are always used. So, to fix it just change your JavaScript to this:

```
let options = ['', '✋', '✌'];
let userBoard = document.getElementById('userBoard');
let computerBoard = document.getElementById('computerBoard');

let app = function () {
  let generatedOptions = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
  let generatedOptions1 = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
  userBoard.innerHTML = generatedOptions
  computerBoard.innerHTML = generatedOptions1
}
```

Now the values of the following variables: `generatedOptions` and `generatedOptions1` change every time the click event is triggered.